# Amplify get video url from storage

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, video, aws-amplify

How can I generate video url from amplify Storage, for images there is a component in
`@aws-amplify/ui-react` but for videos thy didn't provide any component.
Is there a way to generate a url for videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Storage.get()` to access the video:

```
export const getVideo = async (identityId: string) => {
    try {
        const image =
            await Storage.get("Video.mp4", {
                level: "protected",
                identityId: identityId,
                download: true,
                cacheControl: "no-cache",
            })
        return URL.createObjectURL(image["Body"] as Blob);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error getting Video: ", err)
    }
};
```

This examples created the url for the user to download it. Learn more about [Storage from AWS Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started/q/platform/js/).